# Error retrieving parent for item: 'Theme.AppCompat.Light' in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-theme, android-actionbaractivity

I'm trying to use ActionBarActivity in my project. I've imported the android-support-v7-appcompat to the workspace as per the instruction in  https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#

I could add the appcompat project as a library in my current project (eclipse).

[image: Got the Green tick mark]

And now there is no error when I use the following import statement.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

And no error when I extend my class from ActionBarActivity.

```
public class MyClass extends  ActionBarActivity implements ActionBarListener  {....}
```

But, I get errors while using the AppCompat style.

In manifest,

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activity1"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        ....

    </activity>
```

In styles.xml,

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->

</style>


<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

I get the following error in styles.xml while using parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"
** error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.**

Why am I not able to access the resources from the appcompat support library.

P.s: I've not used `android:showAsAction="never"`

Both my application project and appcompat are in the same folder( I copied both to the current workspace).

Comment: Try cleaning your project

Comment: Tried. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked with just a small change in styles.xml

Change

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.AppCompat">
    ...
</style>
```

to

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    ...
</style>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try Replacing your Style.xml with this

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
```

Instead of

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

Comment: Had to use AppCompat or descendant themes as I was using ActionBarActivity. Check out my answer.

Comment: Every other QA on this issue wanted me to import extra libraries that I didn't have or do weird stuff.  This is simple and it works.  Except for DarkActionBar, but I'll figure that out too.  Thanks, Rohit.